# Creating a node att random CGPoint on screen

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to create a shape at a random position on a screen in a universal app.
If I make a `GKRandomDistribution` the `shape.position.x` or `shape.position.y` gives me an error saying that it cannot convert an `Int` into a `CGPoint`.

If I knew the size of the screen this would be easy, but since I want to make this universal all I have to go on is `self.frame` and I can't find a way of saying something like `GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: <min value of screen>, highestValue: <max value of screen>)` for my positions.

I'd love some help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you'll be calling this within one of your SKScene subclasses. If I understand your question correctly, this should do the trick

```
func randomPosition() -> CGPoint {

    let x = CGFloat.random(in: 0...frame.maxX)
    let y = CGFloat.random(in: 0...frame.maxY)
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

}
```